# SimpleDateFormat fails to parse date format in MM/dd/yy

Tags: java, simpledateformat

We have an application where we are parsing date in MM/dd/yy format which works fine for any date upto 2042. But problem occurs when we select date as 2099 which defaults to 1999. Is there any way we can solve this issue

```
 parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
 parseFormat.setLenient(false);
```

Tried by changing the date format to mm/dd/yyyy which works perfectly fine, but I want to parse it as mm/dd/yy itself so that we don't break down our application.

Comment: First question has to be: why are use using `SimpleDateFormat` in 2022?

Comment: our application is old one where they are using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` interprets 2 digit years as between -80 and +20 years of the creation of the formatter instance. `DateTimeFormatter` always interprets 2 digit years as in 2000 - so it solves your issue without and other changes.

Comment: Nope SimpleDateFormat doesn't work in my case if I select date as 2099 which defaults to 1999.

Comment: There's a use case that's why we are not parsing full year as yyyy. I want this to be resolved by parsing date as yy itself.

Comment: just trying to help, ... maybe you should have explained WHAT the use case is.... but writing there is a use case is the same as no information at all  :-(  || solution can be built based on knowledge of the "-80 and +20" range as documented and commented above

Comment: @ani I’m not sure what you mean by your comment. What “case” are you meaning. 2099 is always going to be more than 20 years in the future if you parse a date today - that’s just a fact.

Comment: our backend application consumes in that format and we can never change that..so we need to parse date in mm/dd/yy format itself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider we have UI where the user will select start and end date... and the end date can be of any date greater than start date. So the user is trying to select 2099 as the end date which is defaulting to 1999 which is bad.

Comment: Yes. And as I explained in my comment, `SimpleDateFormat` parses two digit years as -80 to +20 years from the date the formatter was created. I’m not sure what your comments are getting at. Use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: "_where they are using SimpleDateFormat_" they aren't the one writing the code. If you're using Java 8 or higher, you can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), regardless of what _they_ had done. If you're not using Java 8, come back after you upgrade.

Comment: did you eventually meant that the input year is `"99"`, not `"2099"` (`"42"`, not `"2042"`), that is, only two digits, and that it should be interpreted as `2099` and not as `1999`?

Comment: @user16320675 yeah if input year is `"99"` its defaulting to `"1999"` instead of `"2099"`

Comment: Even in old code using the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` in the lines that you are modifying or adding. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a method as [setTwoDigitYearStart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart%28java.util.Date%29) in SimpleDateFormat class where you can mention the century you wan the year to be considered as.

For example below snippet

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    sdf.set2DigitYearStart(new Date());
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date d=sdf.parse("01/01/99");
    System.out.println(d);
```

Outputs to

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 BDT 2099
```

Comment: In my most honest opinion helping users how to use `SimpleDateFormat` is doing them an ill favour. They should rather stop using that class. It is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.